# Which method of a servlet is invoked when I load it by setting it as the welcome file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

If I load a servlet directly using `welcome-file-list` attribute,which method of servlet gets invoke? `doGet()` or `doPost()`?

Comment: It should be `service()` which will delegate the call to your Servlet's `doGet()` if implemented .

Comment: @TheNewIdiot, welcome file will also form a URL, right? so every URL will invoke `doGet` method, right? Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: The URL request will be `GET` , in case if the Container resolves the `request` to a Servlet , then it will invoke the `service()` method of that Servlet , inside the `service()` method the request shall be forwarded to the `doGet()` method because it is a `GET` request.`service()` is a life cycle method , `doGet()` is more of a convenience method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Every URL generates a `GET` request.
- `doGet()` method is invoked by default as the url is `GET` request.
- For `GET` request, `doGet(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)`
  method of servlet is called.

Answer (score 1):

Default method that gets called in servlet is `doGet()`.Clicking a link, a bookmark, entering  URL in browser address bar etc will fire a `HTTP GET` request. If a Servlet is listening on the URL, then it's `doGet()` method will be called. The `HTTP POST` requests are usually only fired by a `<form>` whose method attribute is set to `post`
[Refer this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349633/servlets-doget-and-dopost)