# Tryin to use Jetty as embedded servlet container

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

I want to use Jetty embedded in a java main application to do some quick development. Totally new to Jetty I started by looking at some tuts and examples and here is what I put together:

```
public class JettyTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Server server = new Server(8080);
    server.dumpStdErr();
    ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
    handler.addServletWithMapping(HelloServlet.class, "/*");        
    server.setHandler(handler);
    server.start();
    server.join();
  }
}

class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Override
  public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletResponse httpRes = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    httpRes.setContentType("text/html");
    httpRes.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    httpRes.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello..</h1>");
  }
}
```

And this is the pom's dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <!-- it is 3.1.0 version -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.15.v20160210</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.15.v20160210</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I run that I got this not so promising output on console:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@58651fd0 - STOPPED
 +? qtp1355316001{STOPPED,8<=0<=200,i=0,q=0} - STOPPED
 +? ServerConnector@31ef45e3{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080} - STOPPED
 |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@58651fd0 - STOPPED
 |   +~ qtp1355316001{STOPPED,8<=0<=200,i=0,q=0} - STOPPED
 |   +? 
 org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@754ba872 - STOPPED
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.ArrayByteBufferPool@598067a5
 |   +? HttpConnectionFactory@343f4d3d{HTTP/1.1} - STOPPED
 |   |   +- HttpConfiguration@53b32d7{32768/8192,8192/8192,https://:0,[]}
 |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector$ServerConnectorManager@589838eb - STOPPED
 |       +- null
 |       +- null
 |       +- null
 |       +- null
 |
 +> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
...
```

and when I try to hit the `localhost:8080` I get this:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: edu.jetty.exp.HelloServlet-6fc6f14e@23282359==edu.jetty.exp.HelloServlet,-1,false
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Dunno. Works for me.  :)

Comment: Mind you, I was using an earlier version of Jetty (`8.1.22.v20160922`) and was setting the `Handler` directly, instead of going via a Servlet Mapping

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ServletHandler` directly like that, use a `ServletContextHandler` and add the servlets to that.

As for code examples, there are thousands of examples available on stackoverflow.com alone, even more on other websites.

Some highlights:

- Eclipse Jetty's `examples/embedded` directory - https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-9.4.x/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded
- Jetty Project's Embedded Cookbook - https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook

Also, the `service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse)` method is a very low level API (its not even HTTP!) and is rarely used outside of complex libraries.

If you are just starting out with the Servlet API, consider using the various `do*()` methods instead, such as [`doGet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-) and [`doPost()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-).

See the longer answers at [doGet and doPost in Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349633/doget-and-dopost-in-servlets)