# Server receives the request body as null, when sending post request using okhttp. what could be the issue?

Tags: android, post, servlets, okhttp

This is the Code which is sending the parameters `fname` `selectedFile(byteArray)` as part of the post request body from android to the tomcat server.

```
    public void uploadFile(){
        EditText filename=findViewById(R.id.fileName);
        //content://
        try {
            InputStream inputStream=getContentResolver().openInputStream(filePath);
            selectedFile= IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String purl="http://192.168.1.11:8080/placement/V2TryUploadFile";

        RequestBody requestBody=new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("fname",filename.getText().toString())
                .addFormDataPart("selectedFile",filename.getText().toString(),RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/pdf"),selectedFile))
                .build();
        Request request=new Request.Builder()
                .url(purl)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,filename.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,selectedFile.length+":",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient=new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                call.cancel();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed to Upload",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                final String responseString=response.body().string();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,responseString,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Servlet code (Running on tomcat server) to handle the post request sent from the android add

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String fname=request.getParameter("fname")+".pdf";
        Part selectedFile=request.getPart("selectedFile");
        System.out.println(fname);
        System.out.println(selectedFile+"");
        InputStream filecontent = selectedFile.getInputStream();

        byte[] fileAsByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(filecontent);

        FileOutputStream imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\VAISHAK`\\placeWorkSpace\\placement\\ResumeUploads\\" + fname);
        imageOutFile.write(fileAsByteArray);
        imageOutFile.close();
        doGet(request, response);
    }
```

The issue is fname and selectedFile are not shown null in android app , but both are shown as null in the tomcat server console.

Also Below is the tomcat server log in eclipse

```
null.pdf
null
Apr 13, 2020 11:56:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [trial.V2TryUploadFile] in context with path [/placement] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at trial.V2TryUploadFile.doPost(V2TryUploadFile.java:49)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1623)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException`. So tell us what is `null`. And in which statement.

Comment: Do not use a pointer that is null. Check for null before use.

Comment: @blackapps the problem is.why the post request parameters are null in the servlet. But they are not null when I am sending from the android app in okhttp request

Comment: @blackapps
```
        String fname=request.getParameter("fname")+".pdf";
        Part selectedFile=request.getPart("selectedFile");
```
the above two variabless are null

Due to which the subsequent code throws null pointer exception

Comment: String fname=request.getParameter("fname")+".pdf"; 
Part selectedFile=request.getPart("selectedFile"); 
. As These Statements are null in the servlet, subsequents statements are throwing null pointer exception
@blackapps.. sorry is it clear now

Comment: InputStream filecontent = selectedFile.getInputStream();

Comment: `.setType(MultipartBody.FORM)` Maybe the type is wrong. Did you try doGet() to see if the parameters are there?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349633/doget-and-dopost-in-servlets Have you looked at the third comment?

Comment: @blackapps.. You were right the .setType(MutipartBody.FORM) is wrong. This was because the servlet was not declared for MutipartBody. When i added the annotation 
"@MultipartConfig" to the servlet , it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution

The servlet by default does not handle

```
MutipartBody FORM
```

So in order for it to support that, we need to add the below annotataion to the servlet

```
@MultipartConfig
```